# Updating timestamp automatically on jquery gantt chart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, timestamp

I have created a gantt chart, which acts as a rota shift chart, which is intended for use of delivery drivers and times available. What I want the gantt chart to do is to, update to the current day, each time it is opened. At the moment it is using a unix timestamp to bring up the day and time. the jquery used to load the gantt chart is:

```
     $(".gantt").gantt({
      source: "ajax.php?action=planner",
      navigate: 'scroll',
      scale: 'hours',
      maxScale: 'hours',
      minScale: 'hours'
  });
```

the source used for the information is:

```
case 'planner':

 $json = array();

 $values = array();

 $values[] = array('from' = > '/Date(1344357102000)/', 'to' = > '/Date(1344357102000)/', 'desc' = > '<b>Task #</b>1<br><b>Data</b>: [2011-02-02 09:00:00 - 2011-02-02 12:30:00] ', 'customClass' = > 'ganttRed');
 $json[] = array('name' = > 'Aadil', 'desc' = > 'Progam', 'values' = > $values);

 echo json_encode($json);

 break;
```

Any information on how to update the date automatically without changing the timestamp each time?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a PHP variable as the date.

Check here for more info:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php